# Mapping to a com port

Tags: serial-port

End result first, then my question:
I have a radio unit hooked to serial port (com5) on my server.
I want to be able to send a command to radio from TCIP/IP clients located in another room.

Basically, about 3-4 times a day, I need to change the channel on the radio.  If I issue a command: "NET 20" to the radio, it changes it's channel to channel 20.

Can I "MAP" com ports?
Can I redirect one com port to a port on another machine?

One idea I had was to set the button on my client to write a small file and then transfer that file to the server, and when the server sees the file, execute it.  ie:

```
net21.bat:  
echo net 21 > com5
del net21.bat
```

then when the server sees a .bat file in that directory, execute it.

However the channel change must not take more than 1 second, so the bat file would have to be monitored constantly.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links you should check out:

- http://www.serial-server.net/
- http://pcmicro.com/TCP-COM/
- http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/utilities-tools/com-port-redirector.html

Bear in mind these are not free.